# Python 'NoneType' object query

Tags: python, genetic

I am a Python noob. To learn I'm making a natural selection simulator but I'm a bit stuck.

A bit of background:

I make a list of organisms with random bit patterns, like so:

```
population.append(chromosone.Chromosone(chromosoneSize))
```

Organisms breed, so I have a `@classmethod` to allow an organism to be created based on a combination of it's parents bit patterns, like so:

```
population.append(chromosone.Chromosone.makeChromo(newOrganism))
```

At some points I return the gene from an organism, like so:

def returngene(self):
    """Return the gene"""
    return self.gene

This works for organisms created by `chromosone.Chromosone(chromosoneSize)` but not for organisms created with `chromosone.Chromosone.makeChromo(newOrganism)`. I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'returngene'
```

UPDATE: I have given my makeChromo() a return, like so:

```
@classmethod
def makeChromo(cls, bits):
    obj = cls
    obj.gene = bits
    return obj
```

But I now get this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method returngene() must be called with Chromosone instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

returngene() is a simple method that returns the gene (a string).

I think my misunderstanding lies in the `@classmethod` and how Python works with types and objects?

Comment: what does `maheChromo()` return?

Comment: Also, the word is **chromosome** rather than **chromosone**

Comment: @David Heffernan, noted!

Comment: Thanks for your update. But if we don't see how your `returngene()` is defined, we cannot help you...

Comment: def returngene(self): return self.gene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'returngene'

This error happens when you try to access an attribute on the special `None` object. In your case you are trying to read the method `returngene` in order to call it. Clearly  `population[each]` evaluates to `None`.

Your next step is to work out why `population[each]` evaluates to `None`. Presumably one of the items that you appended to `population` was `None`. And following that through we conclude that one of

```
chromosone.Chromosone(chromosoneSize)
```

or

```
chromosone.Chromosone.makeChromo(newOrganism)
```

returns `None`.

Now you know why this error occurs, you should be able to track down the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you forgot to add a `return` statement to your `makeChromo()` method.

Comment: Giving makeChromo() a return statement gives me: TypeError: unbound method returngene() must be called with Chromosone instance as first argument (got nothing instead). But that's an entirely different error. Do I require a return statement for my @classmethod because it has to return the object it has created?

Comment: @LordKinboat Of course. It only can return something if you tell it to do so. And no one can help you if you don't provide at least a minimal example...

Comment: Apologies, I have a constructor that accepts a value as a length and randomly generates some bits. I needed another constructor so created a class method that accepts a string of bits, like so:

@classmethod
def makeChromo(cls, bits):
  obj = cls
  obj.gene = bits
  return obj

Comment: Why don't you update your question in order to make that suffreadable? So I can only guess: if `cls` is a class to be instantiated, maybe you should do `obj = cls()`. Otherwise, it should work.